# "Bad command-line arguments" error in bash script but not in console

Tags: bash, scripting, arguments

I have a command to execute in a `bash` script. If I run the command directly in the console, it works fine but if I put it in a script and execute the script, it throws the following error:

> Bad command-line arguments

The command I successfully executed in the console is:

```
output=`java -jar myjar.jar -agent iOS -host localhost /Users/vskumar/monkeytalk/workspace/MonkeyProject/'shoppingcart_deleteproduct - Online_V2.mt'`
```

In the script, it looks like this:

```
output=`java -jar $JAR_LOCATION/$JAR_LIST -agent $AGENT_NAME -host $HOST -reportdir $REPORT_DIR/$rep_date $MT_TEST_ROOT_DIR/$SUBSTRING`
```

where the value of `$MT_TEST_ROOT_DIR` is

```
/Users/vskumar/monkeytalk/workspace/MonkeyProject
```

and the value of `$SUSBSTRING` is

```
'shoppingcart_deleteproduct - Online_V2.mt'
```

Comment: Quote your variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you have spaces in the $SUSBSTRING variable that are interpreted as multiple parameters. In order to fix that just put double quotes around your variables:

```
 output=`java -jar "$JAR_LOCATION"/"$JAR_LIST" -agent "$AGENT_NAME" -host "$HOST" -reportdir "$REPORT_DIR"/"$rep_date" "$MT_TEST_ROOT_DIR"/"$SUBSTRING"`
```

Comment: even for those that don't have spaces?

Comment: It is good practice to quote all your variables, you never know when the spaces will strike...